# Не запускается скрипт Python на сервере

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Написан и в командной строке рабочей станции отлажен скрипт на Python3  подтягивающий модель машинного обучения в форме объекта pickle 
Ссылка на скрипт : https://yadi.sk/d/VxdWKojG70id8Q

С командной строки вводится строка в формате: `C:\>anaconda\python.exe D:\1\Execution_prediction.py 107705 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 150000 120000 100000 90000 10000 200000 200000 170000 -1 80 939836 3 252500 20000 D:\1\knn_model.pickle`,

где `C:\>anaconda\python.exe` - путь до Питона, 
`D:\1\Execution_prediction.py` - путь до скрипта, 
`107705 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 150000 120000 100000 90000 10000 200000 200000 170000 -1 80 939836 3 252500 20000` - аргументы на вход в модель,
D:\1\knn_model.pickle - последний аргумент - путь до объекта pickle

У коллег возникает проблема именно с выполнением строки `loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb'))` У коллег даже нет логов ошибок и исключений, выполнение просто останавливается.

Comment: Может быть, `pickle` просто очень медленно работает? В интернетах говорят о том, что этот модуль медленный и небезопасный. Советуют посмотреть в сторону `cPickle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что модель собиралась на версии sklearn 0.19.1, а на сервере стояла сентябрьская версия 0.20, которая находится еще в разработке и окончательно не выпущена, поэтому может быть нестабильна. После отката до 0.19 версии, все заработало.